# why absolutelayout is deprecated?

Tags: android, absolutelayout

why absolutelayout is deprecated? I know that it may cause problems in supporting multiple screens but was better for showing view at particular position.

Answer (score 10):

Because absolute positioning is not too much useful in world of various screen resolutions and aspect ratios. You'd usually leave element positioning to be computed by more flexible layouts.

From docs: *Absolute layouts are less flexible and harder to maintain than other types of layouts without absolute positioning.*

However, if it fits your special purpose, just use it.